# How to post Facebook Feed on Friends wall from IOS application?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

How to post **Facebook Feed** on Friends wall from IOS application?

Comment: The official [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started/) is a good place to start. When posting on SO you need to provide a specific question to a problem that you are facing, you should not just asking for the implementation of a spec.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Social Framework  is very uch useful for sharing and posting  in
  Fb,Twitter .
- Here in the dialog it will ask for privacy we can set that to friends/Piblic/Me

  ```
      if ([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook]) {
      // Initialize Compose View Controller
      SLComposeViewController *vc = nil;
      vc = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];
      // Configure Compose View Controller
      [vc setInitialText:self.captionTextField.text];
      [vc addImage:self.image];
      [vc setCompletionHandler:^(SLComposeViewControllerResult result){
          if (result == SLComposeViewControllerResultDone) {
              [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Congratulations" message:@"Your post is successfully Posted" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil] show];

          }else{
          }
      }];
      // Present Compose View Controller
      [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
  } else {
      NSString *message = @"It seems that we cannot talk to Facebook at the moment or you have not yet added your Facebook account to this device. Go to the Settings application to add your Facebook account to this device.";
      UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Oops" message:message delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
      [alertView show];
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Via Graph API you cannot post to the friend's wall, it was deprecated.

You can use [Feed Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog) to invoke the dialog and user can post the feed to any friend, here's the code:

```
NSMutableDictionary *params =
    [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
        @"An example parameter", @"description",
        @"https://developers.facebook.com/ios", @"link",
        nil];

[FBWebDialogs presentFeedDialogModallyWithSession:nil
    parameters:params
    handler:^(FBWebDialogResult result, NSURL *resultURL, NSError *error) {}
];
```

Check [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog) for more details and list of parameters available.